# Spring security 4 using JavaConfig combining with XML

Tags: java, xml, spring-mvc

I'm trying to implement Spring Security 4 using JavaConfig, but I have no idea how to use it with already implemented XML configuration.

I have SecurityConfig class as follows:

```
package com.wirecard.attendapp.security;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportResource;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@ImportResource({ "classpath:root-context.xml" })
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("root-context.xml");

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().hasRole("USER").and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll().and()
            .logout().permitAll();
}
}
```

And empty SecurityInitializer class:

```
    package com.wirecard.attendapp.security;

    import org.springframework.security.web.context.AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer;

    public class SecurityInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

    }
```

In my root-context.xml I tried to add this, but it's not working:

```
 <beans>
<!-- first, define your individual @Configuration classes as beans -->
<bean class="com.wirecard.attendapp.security.SecurityConfig"/>

<!-- be sure to include the JavaConfig bean post-processor -->
<bean class="org.springframework.config.java.process.ConfigurationPostProcessor"/>
```

In my web.xml I have this :

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
    /WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

How should I use it to work properly? Now it won't load any page from my app. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your security configuration does not need references to `root-context.xml`
2. `SecurityInitializer` does need to reference security [config](https://web.archive.org/web/20161113072407/http://docs.spring.io:80/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/guides/helloworld.html):

   ```
    package org.springframework.security.samples.config;
    import org.springframework.security.web.context.*;

    public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer
          extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

        public SecurityWebApplicationInitializer() {
            super(SecurityConfig.class);
        }
    }
   ```
3. `root-context.xml` does not need the reference to security config - remove it

Comment: It's still same, I won't load any page.

Comment: Here is what I get after loading any page <https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1ODJnlfG-Z9aFZEbGlCVlZYVXc/view?usp=sharing>

Comment: I just see the log which tells me the app stopped because it could not find object with  JNDI name `comp/env/spring.liveBeansView.mBeansDomain`

Comment: that's what happening after creating SecurityWebApplicationInitializer class and I don't know what that means.